# Why promises work differently in loops?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have `delay` function generator to use in `Promise.then` method

```
function delay(msec) {
    return (value) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(value);
            }, msec);
        });
    }
}
```

When I use `delay` function without loop it works fine:

```
var promise = Promise.resolve();
promise
    .then(() => console.log(1))
    .then(delay(1000))
    .then(() => console.log(2))
    .then(delay(1000))
    .then(() => console.log(3))
    .then(delay(1000));
```

But when I use it in loop, all numbers are printed without any delay:

```
var loopPromise = Promise.resolve();
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    loopPromise
        .then(() => console.log(i))
        .then(delay(1000));
}
```

Why promises work differently in loops? How i can fix this loop behavior?

Comment: The "then" construct roughly simulates regular, synchronous behavior. Your loop continues and each timer fires independently, where as the 'then' essentially makes the firing synchronous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why promises work differently in loops?

If we unroll the loop version, you're doing this:

```
var loopPromise = Promise.resolve();

loopPromise
    .then(() => console.log(1))
    .then(delay(1000));

loopPromise
    .then(() => console.log(2))
    .then(delay(1000));

loopPromise
    .then(() => console.log(3))
    .then(delay(1000));
```

IE each one of the calls is going straight onto `loopPromise` and being invoked immediately, rather than being chained.

> How i can fix this loop behavior?

The simplest way is to keep track of the latest part of the chain in each iteration by overwriting your original `Promise` variable:

```
var loopPromise = Promise.resolve();
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    loopPromise = loopPromise
        .then(() => console.log(i))
        .then(delay(1000));
}
```